# Xcode provisioning profile for push notifications

Tags: ios, xcode, nativescript

I'm having a lot of trouble with certificates and provisioning profiles for my iOS app. I've created an App ID and Push notification is enabled on it. The certificates have also been created for development and distribution.

I've created certificates, added my device and finally created the provisioning profiles. In xcode (version 12.4), I selected the dev certificate and profiles but I get error **"MyApp" requires a provisioning profile with the Push Notifications feature.**

In the screenshot, you can see Push notification is one of the capabilities in the profile. I'm not sure what I need to do make xcode recognize this.

[image: Screenshot of xcode]

Comment: You need to fix the profile for the Mac catalyst target or remove it. Why not just tick the box and let Xcode handle all this

Comment: Automatic is messy but I'll let it handle this for now.